# How long does it take to complete a sticker album?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions, average

We are collecing stickers in chocolate bars and whenever we open a bar we get a random new sticker. There are many different stickers and we try to collect them all.

We open the first bar and get a sticker. We open the second bar and we get another sticker, but there is now a chance that it's the one we already got. Doubles are thrown away. As we collect more and more different stickers, the chance gets worse and worse.

So if there are a total of $N$ different possible stickers and we already got $n$, how much chocolate bars $d(N,n)$ do we have to open before we get another one, i.e. the $(n+1)^{th}$ sticker? From this it should also be possible to compute the total number of bars we have to open  (sum of average openings).

Comment: This is the [coupon collecting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: @DavidMitra: Ah okay, thanks - make it an answer and I'll give you green.

Comment: @NickKidman Now that sounds foggy...

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of the basic problems in  probability known to many as the [Coupon collecting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). The Wiki link has a complete solution.

Incidentally, you should be asking about the *expected number* of bars to open to obtain the next, not already collected, sticker, not "how much chocolate bars $d(N,n)$ do we have to open ...".