# Statistics: convergence in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Suppose that you are trying to collect a complete set of $n$ baseball cards. Suppose you buy them one at a time and each time you get a randomly chosen card. Let $N_n$ be the number of cards you have to buy to get the complete set. Show $N_n/(n \ln n) $ converges in probability to 1.

(homework) (convergence in probability)

Comment: I have trouble doing this question, someone please help me out! Thanks

Comment: Your notation is unclear, you should use LaTeX or the formulas. What do you mean by $Nn$, is it $N_n$ or a product?

Comment: Your problem is called "coupon collector" problem. Search stackexchange for that term to get some ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:
1) Express the waiting time as a sum of $n$ independent random variables, each with a geometric distribution.
2) Find the expectation and variance of that sum
3) combine the above information to get to an answer

Comment: +1. Some details [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/28906/6179).

Comment: The convergence is rather slow if the standard deviation of $N_n$ is effectively proportional to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Zombie question, but in case anyone else reads this looking for the answer, I'm going to expand a little bit on the answer given by Kjetil. He gives you the right starting point with writing $N_n$ as a sum of independent geometric r.v.'s, $$N_n = T_1 + T_2 + ... + T_{n-1} + T_n,$$ where $T_i$ is geometric with parameter $i/n$, for $1 \leq i \leq n$. As such, $$\Bbb{E}[N_n] = \sum \Bbb{E}[T_i] \text{ and } \operatorname{Var}(N_n) = \sum \operatorname{Var}(T_i).$$ You can look up formulas for geometric expectation and variance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Properties). (It will also be useful to know the asymptotics of the [nth harmonic number,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and that [$\sum 1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).)

Those are the parts of the answer Kjetil addresses, but the more involved part that his answer glosses over is how to use the expectation and variance of $N_n$ to show that the related r.v. $$X_n := \frac{N_n}{n \ln n}$$ converges to 1 in probability, i.e. $$\Bbb{P}(|X_n - 1| > \epsilon) \to 0$$ for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$.
To show $X_n \to 1$ in probability, we first need to show $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\mu_n - 1| = 0,$ where $$\mu_n = \Bbb{E}[X_n] = \frac{\Bbb{E}[N_n]}{n \ln n}.$$ Then we have to use the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) $|X_n - 1| \leq |X_n - \mu_n| + |\mu_n - 1|,$ together with [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality): $$\Bbb{P}(|X_n - \mu_n| > d) \leq \frac{\sigma_n^2}{d^2},$$ where $$\sigma^2_n = \operatorname{Var}(X_n) = \frac{\operatorname{Var}(N_n)}{n^2 \ln^2 n},$$ to prove the desired convergence in probability.