# The coupon collectors problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

Each box of a certain breakfast cereal contains one of ten different coupons, each with the same probability. We win a prize if we manage to obtain a complete collection of all the different coupons. How long on average do we have to wait? (For example, suppose we draw the following coupons in order: 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 1, 1, 4, 8, 4, 1, 9, 10, 2, 3, 3, 6. With the last coupon 6, we have completed our collection, and so we stop after 17 steps.)

Comment: Main standard coupon collector's problem question seems to be http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) has a writeup of the coupon collector's problem.  If there are $n$ coupons and you already have $k$ of them, the expected time to get the next is $\frac n{n-k}$  This leads to the time to get them all being $n$ times $H_n$, the $n^{\text{th}}$ Harmonic number.  $H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i \approx \log(n)+\gamma$, where $\gamma \approx 0.577$ and you need $n$ times this, so $n \log(n)+n\gamma$

Comment: Shouldn't the *mean* time be $n(\log(n)+\gamma)$?

Comment: @robjohn:  Yes, I fixed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty well known problem.  I think I'll just direct you [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) which has the calculation of the expected waiting time to collect **all** coupons.  Let me know if I can explain any of it to you that is not clear.

Comment: No it is clear,i will look for that