# What is the probability of rolling $n$ dice until each side appears at least once?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

We roll a die until each side appears at least once, then we stop.

> What is the probability of rolling exactly $n$ dice?

I guess the answer is 
$$6-6\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^n\;,$$

but this may be wrong.

In trying to solve this problem, I read [this paper](http://www.madandmoonly.com/doctormatt/mathematics/dice1.pdf), but I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you look for related questions on the site before asking? // Where is your suggestion coming from?

Comment: @Did,Thank you, I have edit.

Comment: 73 pages... Can you be any more specific? And maybe, maybe explain why whatever you are reading can be applied to the situation at hand.

Comment: [Closely related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28905/6179).

Comment: @nanchangjian I am not sure what you are asking.  Is it: if a die is rolled $n$ times, what is the probability that all sides will have appeared at least once?

Comment: @nanchangjian Or is it: if we roll until all sides have appeared, what is the probability that we will stop after $n$ rolls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that what you are asking is: if we roll a die until all sides (i.e. faces) appear, what is the probability that we will roll $n$ times?

In order for this to happen, we need exactly five faces to have appeared in the first $n-1$ rolls, and then the one missing face must appear on the $n$-th roll.  Using inclusion-exclusion, we can express this, for $n>1$, as
$$
p(n) = \frac{1}{6} \binom{6}{5} \left( \left(\frac{5}{6} \right)^{n-1} - \binom{5}{4} \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^{n-1} + \binom{5}{3} \left( \frac{3}{6}\right)^{n-1} - \binom{5}{2} \left( \frac{2}{6} \right)^{n-1}+\binom{5}{1} \left( \frac{1}{6}\right) ^{n-1} \right) 
$$
So, for example, $p(6)=5/324$, $p(7)=25/648$, and $p$ hits a maximum of $875/10368$ at $n=11$.

As a check, you can (numerically) verify that 
$$ \sum_{i=6}^{\infty} ip(i) = 14.7,$$
the well-known expected number of throws needed to see all faces.

Comment: It is not so hard to do it analytically, but it takes some work...

Comment: And who has time for that? A simple sum(i=6,1000,1.0*i*p(i)) = 14.69999999999... satisfies me.

Comment: I know, I know...but remember that not everyone is a programmer/has a CAS/knows WolframAlpha/is a human calculator(But of course everyone should have at least one :))

Comment: Oh, yeah, they definitely should! Go get some CAS now! Cheers!

Comment: I think the derivation can be seen here - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1454749/33.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [coupon collector's problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) Let $N$ be the number of rolls
of a $k$-sided die needed to see all $k$ different values. Then 
$$\mathbb{P}(N=n)= k^{-n}\, k! \,{n-1\brace k-1}.$$
Here ${n\brace k}$ refers to [Stirling numbers of the second kind.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

For example, the probability that we stop on the tenth roll of a six-sided die is 
$$\mathbb{P}(N=10)= 6^{-10}\, 6!\, {9\brace 5}={11585\over 139968}=.08277.$$