# Expected number of rolls on a die until each face has appeared at least twice

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Note: The die is fair, normal 1 - 6 die.

So I understand that the expected number of rolls until each face occurs is 14.7 by the following post: [Expected time to roll all 1 through 6 on a die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die)

but what is the expected number of rolls until each face has appeared at least 2 times?

Comment: isn't it 14.7*2=29.4

Comment: @ADG that's my intuition, because you can simply restart the problem again. But i'm  not sure if that's correct or not, just a guess.

Comment: No, it's not. @ADG, because while waiting for the first complete "set", you will usually roll other faces for the second time. See here [http://www.jstor.org/stable/2308930?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents] for a formula.

Comment: The $o(1)$ is an asymptotic expression, it makes sense only for $n \to \infty$, the number you look for is 
$$ E_2(6) = 6 \int_0^\infty \left[ 1 - \left( 1 - (1+t)e^{-t} \right)^6\right] \, dt. $$

Comment: ... which by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6*int%28+1+-+%281+-+%281%2Bt%29e^%28-t%29+%29^6%2C+t+%3D+0..infinity%29) is about 24.134

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be numerically solved by using the Poissonization trick. This rather unknown but powerful trick (due to A.N. Kolmogorov) is discussed in Chapter 4 of the book *Understanding Probability* of Henk Tijms. This trick leads to the answer

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\big(1-(1-e^{-t/6}-(t/6)e^{-t/6})^6\big)dt\approx 24.134.$

Comment: My reply crossed the reply of Martini. I guess he used the same trick

Comment: With an $n$-faced die with uniform probability, if you wait for all dices to appear $m$ times, the expected number of tries if 
$$ E_m(n) = n \cdot \int_0^\infty \left[ 1 - \left( 1 - e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{t^k}{k!}\right)^n \right]\, dt. $$

Comment: Yes, this would be the correct answer for a symmetric $n$-sided die (coupon collector's problem)