# Expected number of rolls to roll every number

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, dice, classical-mechanics

If I am rolling I die until I roll every number at least once, what is the expected value of times that I will need to roll the die?

After a brief computer simulation, I got 15. But why is this the answer?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die