# How many rolls of a $k$-sided dice should you expect to make before all numbers $1, 2,\dotsc, k$ have been seen at least once?

Tags: probability, expectation

How many rolls of a $k$-sided dice should you expect to make before all numbers $1, 2,\dotsc, k$ have been seen at least once?

Comment: See [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected time to roll all 1 through 6 on a die](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die) Also, formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).