# Expected number of lessons to collect the required cards.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Gottfried has been collecting cards in a competition to win 10 free stats lessons. Each lesson you attend, you get a letter card (S, T or A). To win you need to spell the word (STATS). There is 1000 S, T and A to start with so the chance of getting a S, T and A is equal throughout.

What is the theoretical number of lessons needed to win the competition? And how did you get to this answer? Saw a similar question at: [Expected time to roll all 1 through 6 on a die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die)

But did not help with this one.

Comment: Aparently, the answer is about 9

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You should put your thoughts on the problem in the question, not in a comment.  Also, please explain how you arrived at the thought that it will be about $9$.  Questions where you show no work will attract more votes to close than answers, and many people browsing the questions will not read the comments.

Comment: You should say that the chance of getting S,T, or A  each time is 1/3, so that each hand-out's result is independent of  other handouts. This can be done  by rolling dice, together with the ability to manufacture arbitrarily large numbers of each type of card,. HOWEVER it is NOT the same as having  a  large ,but limited, stockpile of cards. If there are 1000 of each type and your 1st card is S, then your chance of S on the 2nd card is not 1/3. It is 999/2999.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $\frac{311}{36}$. Here is some python code to compute it.

```
import sympy
I = sympy.Integer

def e1(n1, N) :
  return N * n1

def e2(n1, n2, N) :
  if n1 == 0:
    return e1(n2, N)
  if n2 == 0:
    return e1(n1, N)

  e = (I(1)/N * (e2(n1-1, n2, N) + 1) + I(1)/N * (e2(n1, n2-1, N) + 1) + I(N-2)/N) * I(N)/2
  return e

def e(n1,n2,n3) :
  n1,n2,n3 = sorted((n1,n2,n3))
  if n1 == 0 :
    return e2(n2,n3, 3)
  r = 1 + I(1)/3 * (e(n1-1,n2,n3) + e(n1,n2-1,n3) + e(n1,n2,n3-1))
  return r
```

Here is a more generic version that can handle any number of items:

```
class memorize(dict):
  def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func

  def __call__(self, *args):
    return self[args]

  def __missing__(self, key):
    result = self[key] = self.func(*key)
    return result

@memorize
def expected(ns, N) :
  """ Expected number of draws to collect ns[k] items of type k,
      with unifor probability of 1/N for each type.
  expected((2,2,1),3) => 311/36
  """
  assert len(ns) <= N
  if sum(ns) == 0:
    return 0
  ns = sorted(ns)
  while ns[0] == 0 :
    ns = ns[1:]
  n = len(ns)
  if n == 1 :
    return N * ns[0]

  s = 0
  for k in range(n):
    ns[k] -= 1
    s += expected(tuple(ns), N)
    ns[k] += 1
  return (I(N) + s)/n
```

Answer (score 1):

I will write $E(a,b,c)$ to be the expected number of draws to get $a$ of one card, $b$ of another, and $c$ of a third, so that the problem calls for computing $E(1,2,2)$.

We have $$E(1,2,2)= 1 + \frac13E(2,2,0) +\frac23E(1,1,2)\tag{1}$$
because we have to draw a card, and with probability $\frac13$ it is an A so we need $2$ of each of $2$ different cards, and with probability $\frac23$ we draw and S or a T and then we need $1$ of each of $2$ cards and $2$ of another.

Now we continue, expanding the terms on the right-hand side of $(1).$  We have $$E(2,2,0)  = 1+\frac13E(2,2,0)+\frac23E(1,2,0)\tag{2}$$  Again, we must draw a card, and with probability $\frac23$ it's one of the cards we need, but with probability $\frac13$ it's the card we don't want and we still need $2$ of each of $2$ cards.  So we can rewrite $(2)$ as $$ 
\frac23E(2,2,0)  = 1+\frac23E(1,2,0)\tag{2'}$$

In the same way, we expand the other term on the right-hand side of $(1)$ to get  $$
E(1,1,2)=1+\frac23E(1,2,0)+\frac13E(1,1,1)\tag{3}$$

You just have to keep doing this until you get down to terms with known values.  It is well-known that the expected number of trials to get a success in repeated Bernoulli trials with probability of success $p$ is ${1\over p},$ so that $E(1,0,0)=3.$  Also, $E(2,0,0)=6,$ because on average we have to draw $3$ card to get the first S, say, and then another $3$ cards to get the second S.

I'm sure you will be able to finish the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

If $9$ is the correct answer then the expected probability of getting two Ss, two Ts and an A in $9$ lessons would be at or very slightly above $0.5$.

$$P(9) = \frac{\text{Number of ways of getting at least 2 Ss, 2 Ts and an A}}{3^9}$$

$$P(9) = \frac{[\frac{9!}{6!2!}\cdot 2 + \frac{9!}{5!3!}\cdot 2 + \frac{9!}{4!4!}]+2[\frac{9!}{6!2!}+\frac{9!}{5!2!2!}\cdot 2 + \frac{9!}{4!3!2!}\cdot 2]}{3^9} = .5441244$$