# What is the probability that $n$ and no fewer drawings will be required to produce objects of all varieties?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, coupon-collector

There are $k$ varieties of objects, each variety consisting of the same number of objects. These objects are drawn one at a time and replaced before the next drawing. What is the probability that $n$ and no fewer drawings will be required to produce objects of all varieties?

The back of my book says the answer is $\dfrac{ \sum (-1)^r~~~ ^{k-1}C_r(k-r-1)^{n-1}} { k^{n-1} }$

**Attempt:** It is evident that $n > k.$ The problem wants that $n$ and no fewer drawings will be required to produce objects of all varieties.

Thus, there exists at least one variety  $V_i, ~1 \le i \le k$ such that all objects from $V_i$ are drawn together in the end only.

I am not sure how to proceed ahead with the inclusion-exclusion principle. Could someone please give a direction. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Note that whichever variety is drawn on the $n$th draw can't have been drawn on any previous draw (otherwise we would have had all $k$ varieties on the $n-1$th draw).

Comment: @eyeballfrog thats affirmative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected time to roll all 1 through 6 on a die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die)

Comment: This is the famous Coupon Collector's problem. So many questions have been asked about it here that it is hard to say which one to look at first, but we seem to be pointing other questions like this toward https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die, so I've called this question a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eyeballfrog said $n$'th draw must be the last varieties.
Now it like in $n-1$ draw we have $k-1$ varieties without restriction of "And No Fewer Drawing"!

Now drawing $k-1$ varieties is equivalent to skip drawing $1$ variety. If $A_i$ is to skip $i$'th variety, we should compute $|\cup_i A_i|$. By Inclusion-Exclusion Principle we get the nominator of that formula.

Notice $^{k-1}C_r$ is the number of choices of $r$ varieties (to be skipped) from $k-1$ ones.

And $(k-r-1)^{n-1}$ is the number of drawings don't draw those $r$ skipped varieties.

Comment: Could you be a little more detailed , please

Comment: @MathMan I Explained it.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also tell me How to explain the $(-1)^r$ and the summation sign?

Comment: They came from Inc-Exc Principle formula. If you aren't familiar with it, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Shouldn't $^{k-1}C_r$ be the number of choices of $r$ varieties from $k-1$ ones which were **not** skipped ( Since, $A_i$ is that event in which only the $i th$ variety was skipped).

And $(k-r-1)^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: If you could explain the nominator in detail, it would be really helpful

Comment: In fact, $k-1$ ones were not skipped, now we choose $r$ ones from them to be skipped. Read Inc-Exc Principle exactly. There is no more detail. Just first try to understand Inc-Exc Principle concept. Then apply it to problem.

Comment: got it. Thank you !