# Chance of rolling each permutation of a die after passing an initial dice roll

Tags: conditional-probability, coupon-collector

Let's say we have a 20-sided die and a 6-sided die. In order to roll the 6-sided die one time, we must first roll a 20 on the 20-sided die. Our objective is to get to the 6-sided die and roll each number once

**How many rolls should it take us to roll each number on the 6-sided die?**
To me, it seems to be an extension of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

My initial hypothesis is something like (20)*(6/(6-0)) + (20)*(6/(6-1)) + ... (20)*(6/(6-5))

AKA `SUM i=0 to n-1` with (20)*(n/(n-i)), where *n* is subbed in for 6

Looking good? I don't really have anywhere to validate my results, as this is for a personal project

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  Once I throw a $20$, do I then throw the $6$ sided die only?  Or do I only get to throw the $6$ sided die once after each throw of a $20$?

Comment: Nor do I understand your computation.  What's $n$?

Comment: @lulu "I only get to throw the 6 sided die once after each throw of a 20?" <- that's the one. For the computation, n is 6

Comment: Please edit your post to include that explanation...don't leave vital information in the comments only.

Comment: In any case, the problem is essentially equivalent to the question of how many rolls of the six sided die do we expect it to take in order to see all $6$ values.  We expect it to take $20$ rolls to see a $20$ on the twenty sided die, so just add $20$ at each stage of the process.

Comment: Gotcha, updated the problem description. So it looks like 20*6/6 + 20*6/5 + 20*6/4 + 20*6/3 + 20*6/2 + 20*6/1 would aptly describe the number of expected rolls to 'finish' rolling 1-6 on the 6-sided die

Comment: The concept is good, but you have to watch the arithmetic.  Say the six sided die were a one sided die.  Then the answer is $20+1=21$ not $20\times 1=20$.  I suggest working it out carefully for a two sided die before settling on a pattern.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 2):

From the [basic coupon collector's problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die), you need an expected $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{i}$ attempts to get the full set.

So here, with $n=6$, you need an expected $14.7$ rolls of the six-sided die.

For each roll of the six-sided die, you need an expected $20$ rolls of the twenty-sided die to see a $20$, using the geometric distribution.  So in this case you need an expected $20\times 14.7=294$ rolls of the twenty sided die.

So overall you need an expected $14.7+294=308.7$ dice rolls.