# Calculating Probability of getting All Options at least once, with Extra Attempts

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I was looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die) about "Expected time to roll all 1 through 6 on a die" where it was established that the average number of times needed to accomplish this would be 14.7

I understand that that is the average amount of time, but I don't understand how to expand that since the logic doesn't utilize things like combinations or permutations. How would you determine this variant?

"What is the chance that I roll every side on a six-sided dice at least once if I roll it 10 times?"

I'm not certain how to approach this, but I feel like I'm just missing something simple. Should I be using permutations? Or another approach?

Comment: See [Probability distribution in the coupon collector's problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/379525/304635)

Comment: You're not missing anything simple; this is a harder problem than it might look. The answer can be expressed in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind, as explained in jlammy's link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: Linking to a general answer in terms of Stirling numbers is well-meaning, but I'm not convinced that it's helpful.

Comment: @Misha: why? The argument you gave is just a special case of a general formula for the Stirling numbers. I mean to emphasize that the answer is not, say, just some binomial coefficient, so the OP doesn’t need to be worried that they don’t know how to solve it immediately.

Comment: Between the links provided and the example below, I was able to create a thing to help me calculate it. I believe I understand it and was able to apply it to a larger example (which was the final goal). It's still a bit beyond my normal comprehension, but I can follow the steps for now at least. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I guess that's fair. But what I mean is that saying "the answer can be expressed in terms of Stirling numbers" is not interesting when the Stirling numbers are just defined in terms of this problem; the hard part is computing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=1, \dots, 6$, let $A_i$ be the event "in the first $10$ rolls, we never roll $i$". Then $\Pr[A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5 \cup A_6]$ can be expanded out using the inclusion-exclusion principle as:

- the sum of $\Pr[A_1]$ through $\Pr[A_6]$, each of which is $(\frac56)^{10}$;
- minus the sum of all $\binom 62 = 15$ probabilities $\Pr[A_i \cap A_j]$, each of which is $(\frac46)^{10}$;
- plus the sum of all $\binom 63 = 20$ probabilities $\Pr[A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k]$, each of which is $(\frac36)^{10}$;
- minus the sum of all $15$ probabilities $\Pr[A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_l]$, each of which is $(\frac26)^{10}$;
- plus the sum of all $6$ probabilities $\Pr[A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_l \cap A_m]$, each of which is $(\frac16)^{10}$: at this point we're down to cases where we roll only a single number.
- minus the probabilitiy of $\Pr[A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 \cap A_6]$, but that's $0$: at least one value has to be rolled.

This gives us a value of
$$
   6 \left(\frac56\right)^{10} - 15 \left(\frac46\right)^{10} + 20 \left(\frac36\right)^{10} - 15 \left(\frac26\right)^{10} + 6 \left(\frac16\right)^{10} = \frac{101923}{139968}
$$
for $\Pr[A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5 \cup A_6]$, which is the probability that we *don't* see all six outcomes. So the probability we do see all six outcomes is $1 - \frac{101923}{139968} = \frac{38045}{139968} \approx 0.272$.

It's a complete coincidence that this probability is within $0.006\%$ relative error of $\frac{e}{10}$.