# What is the probability of the amount of different numbers obtained after random selection?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $n$ numbers, and each number is different. Randomly select a number with equal probability each time and record it, and repeat this process $t$ times. Note that the number you have selected before can continue to be selected. That is to say, for each selection, the probability of each number being selected is $\frac{1}{n}$. Finally, the amount of digits obtained is $t$. There may be cases where some digits are equal among these $t$ numbers. Repeated digits are deleted and a set of unique elements is obtained. What is the probability $p_{k}$ that the set size is $k$? The value range of $k$ is of course $1\leq k\leq t$. $n$ is much larger than $t$, so there is no need to consider whether $k$ needs to be smaller than $n$. For example, there are $n=1000$ numbers, select $t=40$ times, and finally get $k=35$ non-repeated numbers. What is the probability formula $p_{k}$ for $k$?

For $k=1$, I think $p_1={(\frac{1}{n})}^{t-1}$. And for $k=t$, I think $p_t=\frac{(t-1)\cdot P_n^{t-1}}{n^t}.$ (The $P_x^y$ is number of permutations).

I'm not sure whether these two cases are correct. For $2\leq k\leq t-1$, I didn't find the right way to calculate.

Comment: What is the role of digits in the problem and in which base they are given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the digits play no role and you just found another example of the coupon collector problem.  The answer to your question is:

$$
P_k (n,t)=\frac {n!}{(n-k)!\,n^t}{t \brace k}, 
$$
where ${t \brace k}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind. Details can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4020223).

Comment: Thank you very much, and you have helped me a lot. It's very correct.