# Expected number of distinct toy types after collecting t toys

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

This is a problem from the second edition of *Introduction to Probability* by Blitzstein and Hwang.

Suppose there are $n$ types of toys, which you are collecting one by one. Each time you
collect a toy, it is equally likely to be any of the $n$ types. What is the expected number
of distinct toy types that you have after you have collected $t$ toys? (Assume that you
will definitely collect $t$ toys, whether or not you obtain a complete set before then.)

I attempted to solve this by creating an indicator variable for each type of toy, $I_1,I_2,...,I_n$, each indicator equaling 1 if the toy is collected at least once in $t$ "collections" and 0 otherwise. The probability that a toy type is collected at least once in $t$ "collections" is $(1-(1-1/n)^t)$, and there are $n$ types of toys, so the total expected number of distinct toy types after collecting $t$ toys is $n(1-(1-1/n)^t)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296005/the-expected-number-of-unique-elements-drawn-with-replacement) is a duplicate.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020223/less-common-probabilities-and-expected-values-related-to-the-coupon-collector-pr/4021871#4021871